# How can I pass a v-data-table row information to child element

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have creating a list of users want to add them tags. I am using a data-table to display them and a combo box using chips to add or remove tags. How can I pass the user information to the method called when I add / remove a tag? Here is my code:

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="usersInfos" :search="search" :items-per-page="-1">
    <template v-slot:[`item.tags`]="{ item }">
        <v-combobox v-model="item.tags" :items="roles" chips clearable label="Rôles" multiple>
            <template v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item, select, selected }">
                <v-chip
                    v-bind="attrs"
                    :input-value="selected"
                    close
                    @click="select"
                    @click:close="removeRole(item)"
                >
                    {{ item }} <!-- the tag -->
                </v-chip>
            </template>
        </v-combobox>
    </template>                 
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: pass your ```user information``` with your ```click-event``` .. does that answer your question?

Comment: @B0BBY can you write the code of your answer, I'm not sure that I understand what you mean

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understood it correctly but you can do following pass your `item` with your `click event` to your `methods` - call the function and use the passed parameter there.

*in your template*

```
@click=getSelectedItem(usersInfos)
```

*in your script*

```
methods: {
  getSelectedItem(usersInfos) {
    //do code here
    console.log(usersInfos)
  }
}
```

and than you have to use this where you have written your child element:

```
<child :usersInfo="usersInfo">
```

and in your child.vue you have to set `props` in your `script` like this:

```
props: ["usersInfo"]
```

Comment: Well the problem is that `usersInfos` is an array. It is used by vuetify to construct the `v-data-table`. If I do this, I won't be able to retrieve the info of the user whom I add a tag